# Keep getting Integrity Constraint Violation on checkout/place order/complete order

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, indexing

Here's the problem. I have a constantly running script that adds/changes products' quantities and prices, based on an API from a foreign 3rd party CRM. (Required by the client).

The synchronization is going great, and the products appear and show correctly, as well the quantity and out of stock.

However, the big problem becomes in the checkout! Every now and then (not always) there happens an integrity constraint violation when the user tries to check out.

I have set the index on 'Update on Save', since we're using the Community Edition. Is that the cause of the problem? Will removing the automatic indexing for the prices (which rarely change) and changing to manual mode fix this issue? Or will other indexes also cause this problem?

An example of the stacktrace I'm getting in the log:

```
    Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4418-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_tmp` SELECT `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`entity_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`customer_group_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`tax_class_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`orig_price` AS `price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`price` AS `final_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`min_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`max_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`tier_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`group_price` FROM `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`' in /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(311): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php(564): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(71): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->_movePriceDataToIndexTable()
#7 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(315): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->reindexEntity(Array)
#8 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php(749): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexProductIds(Array)
#9 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer->reindexQuoteInventory(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer), 'reindexQuoteInv...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_model_ser...', Array)
#12 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(191): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_model_ser...', Array)
#13 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#14 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(812): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#15 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(579): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#16 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#17 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#18 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /mnt/webdrive/testing.example.com/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

Comment: Same error here without using any API, maybe this is a magento bug?

Comment: Hello Pat, did  you find any solution to this issue ? i am also using 3rd party import extension RapidFlow for the same price and qty update and after the import is completed , I am having the similar issue.

Comment: Sorry, not really.  This whole thing worked out on its own after reindexing.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and i get it resolved by firing following query which will remove primary key from table.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `catalog_product_index_price_tmp`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `catalog_product_index_price_tmp`;
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_tmp` (
 `entity_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',
 `customer_group_id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Customer     Group ID',
 `website_id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Website ID',
 `tax_class_id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Tax Class ID',
 `price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Price',
 `final_price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Final Price',
 `min_price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Min Price',
 `max_price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Max Price',
 `tier_price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Tier Price',
 `group_price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Group price'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Price     Indexer Temp Table';

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `catalog_product_index_price_tmp`
--
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_tmp`
 ADD KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRICE_TMP_CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID` (`customer_group_id`),
 ADD KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRICE_TMP_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
 ADD KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRICE_TMP_MIN_PRICE` (`min_price`);
```

I have been searching all over the world, but i didn't found any solution for the same. The issue happen mostly when a simple product of configurable having last quantity.

Tables starting with _tmp are the temporary tables, Updating such table will not create any issue in future.